# How to p2p_connect to device with WiFi Direct without MAC Address? (Raspberry Pi and Android)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, wpa-supplicant

I have an Android tablet and A Raspberry Pi and I want to established a connection between them automatically when the tablet sends a request to the Pi.

I followed an Android application example here and start discovering any nearby devices. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnY97iBxp30)

At the same time i run sudo wpa_cli and p2p_find 20. The Android application detects the Pi, and I try to establish connection with the Pi which will display

`<3>P2P-GO-NEG-REQUEST TABLET_MAC_ADDRESS dev_passwd_id=4`

Normally I would just `p2p_connect TABLET_MAC_ADDRESS pbc` to successfully connect them together but I find it inefficient if I were to swap to another mobile device.

Are there any other ways to connect the tablet without writing the tablet mac  address? For example connecting to that specific device ssid when they send a `P2P-GO-NEG-REQUEST` to the pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Nope.
If we look at the [OSI ISO 7 layer model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) for network communication we can see that the Media Access Control (MAC) address is vital for identifying which device is which within a wifi network.
You could try setting up a bluetooth connection or a token-ring, but I suspect that would be more effort than you are looking for.
With IPv6 your devices could use neighbour discovery to automate past the MAC entry to the Internet Protocol, and its possible to connect between devices using their link-local address (fe80::some:thing)

Wifi carries packets of data, that have addresses. By analogy, if I tell you which town I live in, but don't write my building address on the packet, you are going to have a hard time delivering it.